# Complex Scripts in Vim and gVim

Tags: vim

I am learning Vim, and it is great. But the problem with Vim and gVim is that it doesn't support any complex scripts like Devanāgarī; it is not rendered properly. See the screenshots below:

**Rendering in Vim:**

[image]

**Correct Rendering (in gEdit, Emacs, KWrite):**

[image]

Is there any way to make Vim or gVim support complex scripts? This affects all Indic scripts. I tried changing the font just in case, but it didn't help.

Comment: THis is the text - अनन्त: वै वेद:

Comment: If I go on typing with the incorrect rendering(which is not readable), and save it and check that file is gedit, the text is all written correctly. There is only problem in display in Vim.

Comment: If this rendering is incorrect even with the font that supports Indic scripts, post a bug to [vim-dev](http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/subscribe?hl=en_US) mailing group. I do not think that this will be fixed soon, but you may find someone who knows gvim sources enough to write a patch.

Comment: Don't you think it is more of a problem of gnome-terminal which gvim uses(I guess) ?

Comment: I guess not: I have no gnome-terminal installed, but gvim still works. In fact, it even does not use gtk unless you tell it so: gvim on my system is compiled without gtk use flag and ldd also shows that it uses libX* and not on gtk.

Comment: Ya! I posted regarding this in vim mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

Check:

```
set fileencoding
set encoding
```

Also check again the font. Not all font support everything.

Comment: Ya! I did set fileencoding=utf-8 and set encoding=utf-8 but still no difference.

Comment: Yes! Did checked the font. That font works fine in gedit or any other text editors.

Comment: Yes! that might work for other font's but Indic Script have complex rendering rules, so they are called Complex Scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Change the font in vim to the default font in gEdit (or whatever editor you were using in screenshot #2). Is the rendering incorrect with the same fonts?

Answer (score 0):

Vim in gnome-terminal seems to be correct as it uses the same routines for rendering as gedit does (default Ubuntu 10.04).

Comment: I am using GNOME Terminal 2.28.1. It is not working. Is this the version you have ? Will this make any difference ? The rendering of complex characters is wrong in gnome-terminal itself.

Comment: Even that rendering is wrong. It somewhat-seems right only due to the use of simple characters. Anyway it is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of the `iminsert` option.
Specifically, try setting

```
:set iminsert=2
```

Comment: Hmm... No change same rendering problem.

Comment: It's hard to understand what settings exactly are responsible for  that, but it works in my system: the rendering is the same in GVim and GEdit...

Comment: @ib can you post full output of `set` called without arguments?

Comment: Here is how it looks after pasting into an empty buffer: http://imgur.com/xk9EM.png

Comment: May be this issue is somehow related to X settings?  For example, I'm using X Input Method system-wide.  But, again, GVim and any Gtk application reders it correctly.  And, by the way, Vim in XTerm also works as expected, I believe.

Comment: At least, it renders exactly the same way as in any Gtk application on my system like Gedit.